# Google Sheet Functions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

A1=15, B1=20

Which Function should I used and how should I write it if I wanted C1 to show A1+B1>35, minus 35, if A1+B1<35, keep it at it is without changing anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IF(A1+B1>35; (A1+B1)-35; A1+B1)
```